# group by and set column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question about pandas DataFrame manipulation.
say I have a data frame

```
    DF
    A   Date    C
0   1   1-jan   0
1   1   2-jan   1
2   1   3-jan   0
3   2   4-jan   0
4   2   5-jan   0
5   2   6-jan   1
6   3   7-jan   1
7   3   8-jan   0
8   3   9-jan   0
```

If we assume that column A is account_ids, what I want to do is, for each account, to set the column C value to 1 if we have already observed 1 in that Column C until that date(based on Date column). *For example, for account number 1 I will make all values in C column equal to 1 after 2nd of January. For account number 3 all C column values will be 1 after 7th of January.*

```
    Output
   A    Date    C
0   1   1-jan   0
1   1   2-jan   1
2   1   3-jan   1
3   2   4-jan   0
4   2   5-jan   0
5   2   6-jan   1
6   3   7-jan   1
7   3   8-jan   1
8   3   9-jan   1
```

Comment: You'd better make it more readable, and highlight what you're trying to do, Figuring out what's going on with the two dfs is confusing.

Comment: Sorry for being vague, I have tried to make the description clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['C'] = df['C'].replace(0 , np.nan)
df['C'] = df.groupby('A')['C'].fillna(method = 'ffill').fillna(0)



Out[14]:
    A   Date    C
0   1   1-jan   0
1   1   2-jan   1
2   1   3-jan   1
3   2   4-jan   0
4   2   5-jan   0
5   2   6-jan   1
6   3   7-jan   1
7   3   8-jan   1
8   3   9-jan   1
```